# Slicing a torch tensor with an arbitary sized tuple

Tags: pytorch

Can I use a tuple with an unspecified length for slicing (or equivalently, a matrix with an unspecified number of columns)?
For example, I want to slice `x` using `ind` and `ind2`. `ind2` is a 1D tensor. If `ind` is a tuple containing a single 1D vector, then I want to get `x[ind[i],ind2[i]]`. If ind contains two 1D vector, I want to obtain `x[ind[0,i], x[ind[1,i], ind2[i]]`, etc.